# Trying to prove a function is increasing in one variable after the second variable crosses a particular value.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Let $f(p,n)$ = $\ln\bigl(1 + \frac{ap}{b+I}\bigr) + \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\ln\bigl(1+ \frac{b_j}{b + I - b_j + ap}\bigr)$,

where $b>0$ and $a>0$ are fixed constants. The positive real numbers $b_j$ are such that $\sum_{j =1}^{n}b_j = I$. Assume $b_0 < b_j \leq K$, where $b_0$ is a fixed strictly positive constant. The 
variables $p \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does there exist a positive real number $I_0$ such that the function $f(p,n)$ is non decreasing in the variable $p$ $\forall I \geq I_0$. (Note that 'n' can be made arbitarily large.)

I tried the following: Let $0 \leq p_1 < p_2$, then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
 f(p_2,n) - f(p_1,n) = \ln \biggl(1+ \frac{a(p_2-p_1)}{b+I+ap_1} \biggr) + \sum_{i =1}^{n}\bigl(g(0)-g(b_j)\bigr),
\end{eqnarray}$$
where
$$\begin{eqnarray}
g(x):= \ln\biggl( 1 + \frac{a(p_2-p_1)}{b+I-x+ap_1} \biggr).
\end{eqnarray}$$ 
Applying Mean value theorem, we get 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
g(0) - g(b_j) = \frac{-a(p_2 -p_1)b_j}{(b+I-c_j +ap_2)(b+I-c_j +ap_1)},
\end{eqnarray}$$
where $c_j \in (0,b_j)$.
Applying bounds we get 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
g(0) -g(b_j) \geq \frac{-a(p_2 -p_1)b_j}{(b+I-B +ap_2)(b+I-B +ap_1)},
\end{eqnarray}$$
hence 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
f(p_2,n) - f(p_1,n) \geq \ln \biggl(1+ \frac{a(p_2-p_1)}{b+I+ap_1} \biggr) - \frac{a(p_2 -p_1)I}{(b+I-B +ap_2)(b+I-B +ap_1)}.
\end{eqnarray}$$
I am unable to proceed further on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.